# Can't get value from xpath python

Tags: python, html, xpath, web-scraping, html-parsing

I want to get values from page: http://www.tabele-kalorii.pl/kalorie,Actimel-cytryna-miod-Danone.html
I can get all values from first section, but I can't get values from table "Wartości odżywcze"

I use this xpath:

```
''.join(tree2.xpath("//html/body/div[1]/div[3]/article/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[3]/table[1]/tr[3]/td[2]/span/text()"))
```

But I'm not getting anything.

With xpath like this:

```
''.join(tree2.xpath("//html/body/div[1]/div[3]/article/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[3]/table[1]/tr[3]/td[2]//text()"))
```

I'm getting word 'kcal', but can't get value '75,00'

Html snippet:

```
<td style="font-weight:bold;"><span id="kcl715">75,00</span> kcal</td>
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: this should work: `''.join(tree2.xpath("//html/body/div[1]/div[3]/article/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[3]/table[1]/tr[3]/td[2]/span//text()"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values in the table are generated with the help of *javascript being executed in the browser*.

One option to approach it is to automate a browser via [`selenium`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org), e.g. a headless `PhantomJS`:

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>>
>>> driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
>>> driver.get("http://www.tabele-kalorii.pl/kalorie,Actimel-cytryna-miod-Danone.html")
>>>
>>> table = driver.find_element_by_xpath(u"//table[tbody/tr/td/h3 = 'Wartości odżywcze']")
>>> for row in table.find_elements_by_css_selector("tr.tr-gorna-kreska"):
...     cells = [td.text for td in row.find_elements_by_tag_name("td")]
...     print cells
... 
[u'Warto\u015b\u0107 energetyczna', u'75,00 kcal', u'75,00 kcal']
[u'Bia\u0142ko', u'2,70 g', u'2,70 g']
[u'W\u0119glowodany', u'11,80 g', u'11,80 g']
[u'T\u0142uszcz', u'1,50 g', u'1,50 g']
```